# Simple String Encryption in C

Tags: c, string

I'm attempting to create a very simple encryption where a string is scanned, and the ascii code is increased by 5 (+5). When the letters reach the end of the alphabet it wraps back around to the beginning (same with numbers). punctuation and any other symbols are not encrypted. The encryption function seems to be working, however I'm having trouble passing the string back to the main function. What has gone wrong?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*function definitions */
char encrypt(char input_string[]);

int main(void)
{
  char input_string[25];
  char new_string[25];
  char encrypted_string[25];
  int i = 0;

  // scan word
  printf("Enter word: ");
  scanf(" %[^\n]", input_string);
  fflush(stdin);

  //check input
  printf("%s\n", input_string);

  // call encrypt function
  encrypted_string[25] = encrypt(input_string);

  // print encrypted version
  printf("encrypted: %s\n\n", encrypted_string);

  return 0;

}

char encrypt(char input_string[])
{
   char new_string;
   static char str[25];
   int i;

   for(i = 0; i < 25; i++)
     {
         if (input_string[i] > 96 && input_string[i] < 118) // for a - u
           { 
                new_string = (input_string[i] + 5);  
           }
         else if (input_string[i] > 117 && input_string[i] < 123) // for v - z
           {
                new_string = (input_string[i] - 21);       
           }
         else if (input_string[i] > 64 && input_string[i] < 86) // for A - U
           {
                new_string = (input_string[i] + 5);       
           }
         else if (input_string[i] > 85 && input_string[i] < 91) // for V - Z
           {
                new_string = (input_string[i] - 21);       
           }
         else if (input_string[i] > 47 && input_string[i] < 53) // for 0 - 4
           {
                new_string = (input_string[i] + 5);       
           }
         else if (input_string[i] > 52 && input_string[i] < 58) // for 5 - 9
           {
                new_string = (input_string[i] - 5);       
           }
         else
           {   
                new_string = input_string[i];
           }

      str[i] = new_string;

     }

  printf("\n\n");

  i=0;

  //check asccii codes
  while(str[i])
    {
         printf("%d ", str[i++]);
    }

  //print string
  printf("\n\n%s\n\n", str);

  //return string to main
  return(str[25]);
}
```

Comment: You need a few more C tutorials and practice before stepping into encryption (or cryptography in general). The problem with crypto is that you never really get good errors, just random data if you use it improperly.

Comment: You can't really "return a string" from a function in C. C passes parameters by value and returns values, and C has no string value type. If a function needs to build a string, you need to either (1) have the caller allocate space for it and pass that address and length into the function for it to modify (see, e.g., snprintf()), or (2) dynamically allocated it in the function and trust the caller to free it when needed.

Answer (score 3):

`return(str[25]);` means you're trying to return the *value* of the 26th element,[which is out-of-bound access], not the address of the string.

`encrypted_string[25] = encrypt(input_string);`
No, you cannot assign a string return like that. It's wrong in many ways.

To correct, follow the below steps.

1. change `char encrypt(char input_string[])` to `char* encrypt(char input_string[])`
2. use `return(str);` instead of `return(str[25]);`
3. instead of `char encrypted_string[25];`, write `char * encrypted_string;`

NOTE:

using `static` array will do the job, but IMO, a better approach will be allocating the array dynamically and return the pointer after populating from `encrypt()` function. You can later `free()` the pointer from `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your function:

```
char encrypt(char input_string[])
```

literally says that it accepts a long string as input, and returns just a single character as output.
That seems very dubious.

Don't you want it to return a string as output, not just one letter?